# who are click on my Deep Links in telegram?

Tags: python, bots, telegram

I'm creating a bot for absorb members.The robot in this way act:
I send a unique link to my bot users, then users send own unique link to other.by this way other absorb to my bot.
I create a Deep  Link for bot, and now i want to know who are click on own Deep Links.

Comment: https://core.telegram.org/bots#deep-linking

Comment: deep link used to start a bot, when a person starts a bot u can get some info from him(whether user start bot with deep link or not).

Comment: salam.man mikham ye robat dorost konam ke be har shakhs link ekhtesasi bede.aezaye robat ba estefadeh az link ekhtesasiye khodeshoon be robat ozve jadid miarand.ta inja ba estefade az deep linking sakhte mishe.va inke mikham bedoonam har kesi ke ozve robat shode az tariqe kodom ozv oomade.in robat ro be esme robate jazbe member mishnasand.

Comment: Why you are talking persian? Here is an English forum.  just give each member a unique I'd, and save it. When a person joined robot get that deep link and find his superior

Comment: ok.I can give to everyone unique link.but i cant make table of subuser.subuser is the user that join to bot by others link.

Comment: I want track unique link and get table that contains info about users join the bot by unique link.

Comment: Can u view unique id when a person join bot?

Comment: yes . it seen when the user ask own unique link.the user click on button and send for him unique link.

Comment: Every time a user joined bot save unique Id of his superior and his unique id in a database.

Comment: Yes. I create database by sqlite3 in python then every one send /start to the bot , i get his unique id,  how can i get his superior unique id?Telegram just save current user info.

Comment: Can you send me a pm in telegram?  @conficker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [Telegram Documentation](https://core.telegram.org/bots#deep-linking):

when a person join bot with `/start` command if any additional parameters pass to bot-link you receive a message in this form:

`/start PAYLOAD`

Which `PAYLOAD` stands for the value of the `start` parameter that was passed in the link.

So for example in `telepot` library:

```
def handle(msg):
    content_type, chat_type, chat_id = telepot.glance(msg)

    if content_type == 'text':
        text = msg['text']
        print('Text:', text)

        if text.startswith('/start'):
            try:
                command, payload = text.split(' ')
                print('Payload:', payload)
                print('chat_id:', chat_id)
```